# Chrome driver exception on Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium 2.53.1.jar, platform-Windows, Java- 1.8, chrome = 52.0, chrome-driver.exe-2.23.

I am seeing the following message when trying to run Night watch test on Jenkins.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to
>   discover open pages   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699
>   (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT
>   6.3.9600 x86_64)

Please note that the test is running correctly from the command line- all paths given are same as in the Jenkins job.

I also tried a previous version 2.22 of Chrome driver. Still see the same error.
Test is running correctly on FF.

Comment: you need to put the chrome driver into the slave machine that is connected to Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm getting the same error. Maybe you can try putting sand-box for chrome. Maybe that might help you out temporarily.